# Run bash command for currently selected line

Tags: atom-editor

I'd like to be able to hit a shortcut like `cmd-shift-r` and have that automatically run a bash command, say, `mix test test/turtle/api/v3_test.exs:72`.

In other words: `mix test {FILE_ACTIVE}:{FILE_ACTIVE_LINE_NUMBER}`

What is the best way to accomplish this? Is there an atom package that takes care of this or something I could write quickly myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you care about the output of the bash command?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the output. The main use case is for my desired workflow. I'm writing a test in Atom and want to run only that test by hitting a shortcut. Would like to see the results of whether it passed for failed.

Comment: I'm making an assumption that you are writing Elixir tests, does the [Elixir compiler for Atom](https://github.com/AtomBuild/atom-build-elixir) work for you?  If it does I would suggest grabbing the source code and adding the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSlater I haven't looked at that package. I was hoping to build something that has to know nothing about the language. All I need is the active file path and line number so I can translate that into a terminal command.

Comment: Understood, I will put something together for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fairly low-fi way to get this to work using your `init.coffee` load this by going to `File` → `Init Script...` or by choosing `Application: Open Your Init Script` from the Command Palette.

1. Add the following to the bottom of your `init.coffee`:

   ```
   atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
     'custom:execute-this-test': ->
       if editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
         row = editor.getCursors()[0].getBufferRow() + 1
         path = editor.buffer.file.path
         {spawn} = require 'child_process'
         mix = spawn 'mix', ['test', "#{path}:#{row}"]
         mix.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
           atom.notifications.addError data.toString()
         mix.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
           atom.notifications.addInfo data.toString()
         mix.on 'exit', (code) ->
           atom.notifications.addInfo "Exited with Code #{code}"
   ```
2. Save the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and reload the text editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.
3. Once Atom has restarted, find the line in the file you want to execute the code against and open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and search for `Execute This Test`.

You may want to tweak the code to be reduce the amount of output it generates, however the above is probably enough to get you started.  If you wanted to optimize the workflow even further you can [create a Keybinding](http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/).

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help. I'll give this a spin tonight and post back :)

Comment: It worked great. I made a tweak to the script--I passed in the current working directory for the command. I'll take your suggestion and trim down the generated output as a next step. Thanks!